# Importing Android External Libraries into a Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, flutter-dependencies

How to integrate external libraries successfully into the flutter project.

I have an external SDK samplelib.aar file and I need to use it in my application.

I added External Android SDK samplelib.aar file in android/libs/ folder and added its dependencies in the build.gradle line as below.

```
compile(name:'samplelib', ext:'aar')
```

I have added the dependencies section in the gradle file as below.

```
repositories { flatDir { dirs 'libs' } }
```

**now i need to import the library packages in .java file but I am unable to do it.**

I am in need to do this. So can help on this with the possible ways to add external .aar file in flutter for android

Answer (score -1):

You need to use platform channel to invoke platform specific code. You can see details here on flutter documentation page: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example-java

So, after create you platform specific stuff accessing the specific libs that you added on gradle files, you must to use a MethodChannel in your dart code to invoke it.

Comment: The question is not about how to invoke a Java method from Dart. It's about how to include a Java library into the android section.